# How do I let sed 'w' command know where the filename ends?

Tags: file, bash, unix, sed

Every example I was able to find demonstrating the `w` command of `sed` has it in the end of the script. What if I can't do that?

An example will probably demonstrate the problem better:

```
$ echo '123' | sed 'w tempfile; s/[0-9]/\./g'
sed: couldn't open file tempfile; s/[0-9]/\./g: No such file or directory
```

(How) can I change the above so that `sed` knows where the filename ends?

P.S. I'm aware that I can do

```
$ echo '123' | sed 'w tempfile
> s/[0-9]/\./g'
...
```

Are there prettier options?

P.P.S. People tend to suggest to split it in two scripts. The question is then: is it safe? What if I was going to branch somewhere after the `w` command, and so on. Can someone confirm that *any* script can be split in two after *any* command and that will not affect the results?

**Final edit:** I checked that multiple `-e` work just as concatenated commands. I thought it was more complex (like the first one should always exit before the second one starts, etc.). However, I tried splitting a `{..}` block of commands between two scripts and it still worked, so the `w` thing is really not a serious problem. Thanks to all.

Comment: Why don't you just split it into multiple command like `echo '123' | sed -e 'w tempfile' -e 's/[0-9]/\./g'`. Does that not do what you want?

Comment: @Celada The actual case is more complex, and everything is inside a recursive "label"; perhaps I still can split it somehow, but it may be challenging and also I'm not sure it can always be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a two line script to sed in one shell line:

```
echo '123' | sed -e 'w tempfile' -e 's/[0-9]/\./g'
```

Comment: Does it work as a two-line script or as two scripts? Can I always break a script in two like this without breaking the logic?

Comment: If you `cat tempfile` after this command, it still shows `123`.

Comment: @anubhava As I wrote above, I'm concerned about more complex cases involving flow control. So I'm curious if it can be done always, not only for this simple command.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (if you're using BASH and probably GNU sed):

```
echo '123' | sed 'w tempfile'$'\n'';s/[0-9]/\./g'
```

Explanation:

The `r`, `R` and `w` commands need a newline to terminate the file name.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is "newline":

`sed` will treat a non-escaped literal newline as the end of the file name.

If your shell is bash, or supports the `$'\n'` syntax, you can solve the OP's original question this way:

```
echo '123' | sed 'w tempfile'$'\n''s/[0-9]/\./g'
```

In a more limited `sh` you can say

```
$ echo '123' | sed 'w tempfile'\
> 's/[0-9]/\./g'
```

What I did here was write `\` as an escape, then hit enter and wrote the rest of the command there. Note that here I am escaping the newline from `bash` but it is being passed to `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the 2 sed command sequences like this:

```
echo '123' | sed 's/[0-9]/\./g;w tempfile'
```

i.e. perform replacements first and then write pattern space into a file.

**EDIT:** There was some misunderstanding whether OP wants replaced text in final file or not. My above command puts replaced text in tempfile. Since this is not what OP wanted here is one more version that avoids it:

```
echo '123' | sed -e 'h;s/[0-9]/\./g;g;w tempfile'
```

Comment: @LevLevitsky: Please see my edited answer, it can be done in single sed command without breaking it into 2.

Comment: The order was intended. Sorry, my example must have been misleading.

Comment: Ah I thought you wanted replaced results as well in tempfile.